# MSBuild Windows Kits 10 error with objidl.idl

Tags: tfs, sdk, msbuild, tfsbuild

Trying to build my solution with MSBuild 15.0 from TFS2017 server, I have the following errors:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\objidl.idl (702, 0)
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\objidl.idl(702,0): Error MIDL2072: inapplicable attribute : [ Type 'SNB' ( Interface 'IStorage' ) ]

and

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\objidl.idl (742, 0)
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\objidl.idl(742,0): Error MIDL2072: inapplicable attribute : [ Type 'SNB' ( Parameter 'snbExclude' ) ]

I have tried different versions of \include, \lib, \bin folders such as:

- 10.0.17134.0
- 10.0.16299.0
- 10.0.10586.0
- 10.0.10240.0

to no avail.

Any ideas or help how to resolve this issue are highly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: What's the result if you manually remote to build agent and directly build use Visual Studio  instead of TFS build? This will narrow down if the issue is related to your environment or TFS side. According to the error info, seems the issue should more related to SDK. Please make sure your local environment is as same as your build agent/server environment. Besides also take a look at this similar question, which maybe helpful to you: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/165191/error-midl2072-inapplicable-attribute-annotation-t.html

Comment: I had environment path set to win sdk 6.1 as well as windows kits 10, removing the sdk 6.1 from the path variable fixed this issue, so I can confirm what the guy from that link said, target only 1 sdk in your env path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First please make sure your local environment is as same as your build agent/server environment.

Besides, also take a look at this similar question, which maybe helpful to you:

[error MIDL2072: inapplicable attribute : [annotation] [ Type 'SNB' ( Interface 'IStorage' )](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/165191/error-midl2072-inapplicable-attribute-annotation-t.html)

Give a try with the solution mentioned in the link:

> Remove all references on older SDK's binary directories in 'Executable
>   Directories' for 'VC++ Directories' in Properties for
>   'Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user'; otherwise the wrong (previous) version of
>   the MIDL compiler (that doesn't understand newer SAL/MIDL syntax) will
>   run with possible errors.